# Setting value of private property

Tags: c#, properties, mocking

I am trying to test my class

```
public class Parser
{

    private static IDictionary<String, Regex> PhrasesToRegexp { get; set; }

    public static void InitPhrases(IList<String> Phrases, Boolean useDeclination )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ...

    public ParsingResults Find(String source)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(source);
        return new ParsingResults(FindUrls(doc), CountPhrases(doc));
    }



    private IList<String> FindUrls(HtmlDocument source)
    {
        return source.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").
            Select(link => link.GetAttributeValue("href", "")).ToList();
    }

    private IDictionary<String, int> CountPhrases(HtmlDocument source)
    {
        IDictionary<String, int> results = new Dictionary<String, int>();
        foreach (String key in PhrasesToRegexp.Keys)
        {
            results.Add( key , 0 );
        }

        foreach (HtmlNode node in source.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
        {
            foreach (String phrase in results.Keys)
            {
                results[phrase] += PhrasesToRegexp[phrase].Matches
                    (Regex.Replace(node.InnerText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty)).Count;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

The thing is that property `PhrasesToRegexp` is (will be) initialized in `InitPhrases` and I am trying write unit test for method Find. Basicly i need to set value of this private property `PhrasesToRegexp`. Is there any way to do that? I am no expert in mocks but i think they will not do the trick since this property and tested method are in the same object.

Comment: Your tests are giving you feedback about your design; why are you ignoring it? Code that is hard to test needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new constructor specifically for unit tests, but I would advise minimising any changes to your class to make it unit-testable. Specialisations to support unit tests usually mean that you aren't testing the actual code that will run in the final application. The further you specialise it, the harder it is to be sure that the real code is being fully tested, and the more chance there is of introducing unwanted side effects into the code under test.

Instead, (if possible) I try to use the class as a client would - if you construct the instance and call the method as a client would, you shouldn't need to poke about in private state, and your unit test will test exactly what any client code will use. Also, your test is more likely to remain valid/effective if you change the internal workings of the class, as there is no special pathway for unit tests that you can forget to keep in sync with the code changes.

If you prefer to expose the property and prod it directly, then changing it to `internal` and using `InternalsVisibleTo` is a standard approach, but it offends my sense of encapsulation as it becomes permanently internal for everybody. How is another programmer to know that you mean "internal for testing" rather than "hey, we're good friends, please party on my internal state as much as you like". What is private there for if we just throw it away when we want to unit test? So another approach, which keeps the code private, is to use a special build for unit testing, which sets a #define to allow you to expose the privates you want to access for tests, while leaving them private in your normal build.

One way is brute force on the property itself (but this can be quite messy):

```
#if UNIT_TEST
    public
#else
    private
#endif
int MyPrivateProperty { get; set; }
```

Or, a cleaner approach (but more work) is to leave the original code unscathed and add access methods, to minimise the chance that you inadvertently break/alter the code under test.

```
private int MyProperty { get; set; }

#if UNIT_TEST
    public int AccessMyProperty
    {
        get { return(MyProperty); }
        set { MyProperty = value; }
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Unit Test project I've created a MockClass which extends the original class, no methods or properties are rewritten.

- **Original class**: the property which was private is promoted to protected.
- **Mock class**: Created a public method which sets the protected property.

With this approach you don't have to change visibility to internal, which is a lot more visible than protected. Of course it also means that if a developer wants to acces your property he is able to by extending your class, in the same manner as your unit test does.

```
public class Parser
{
      protected static IDictionary<String, Regex> PhrasesToRegexp { get; set; }
      ...
}

public class MockParser : Parser
{
     public MockParser() : base()
     {
     }

     public void AddPhraseToRegexp(String key, Regex value)
     {
         // Add it
         PhrasesToRegexp.Add(key, value);
     }

     public void CreatePhrasesToRegexp(IDictionary<String, Regex> newDict)
     {
         // Create a new Dictionary
         PhrasesToRegexp = newDict;
     }
}
```

**NOTE: this does NOT work for static or sealed classes**

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible depending on mocking framework you are using. I usually use Moq or NMock2, and in those cases the viable options are:

1) Make the property internal instead of private, which allows you to set it in unit test. You may have to use InternalsVisibleTo attibute if your unit tests are in separate project.

2) Create a separate constructor for unit test purpoeses that will accept PhrasesToRegexp

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of `private` you should declare it as `internal`.

2) In AssemblyInfo.cs you should add the assembly, from there your class will be accessed like follows

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MainFormUnitTests")]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem is arising because you are expressing two different concerns in your parser.

1. A quick reference cache for your phrases and regex
2. The parsing logic

I would suggest splitting out these two concerns into two different classes.  Besides, you might want to address clearing out the memory of the static dictionary at some point (or invalidating the cache).

If you take the caching logic out behind a `ICachePhrasesAndRegex` interface then you can easily mock the dependency for testing.